# Is the September 11th the only time a plane was crashed into skyscrapers?

Tags: accidents, accident-statistics

I wonder if there has been other plane crashes with skyscrapers in history, except the one of the World Trade Center.

Comment: It was attempted in 1994 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Express_Flight_705

Comment: There were threats to intentionally crash into a nuclear reactor in 1972 on Southern Airways flight 49.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Airways_Flight_49

Answer (score 11):

Intentionally with a large aircraft, yes. There was however an instance in 1945, where [a B-25 Mitchell collided with the Empire State building](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/1945_Empire_State_Building_B-25_crash). This however was an accident.

There have been several suicides by airplane where the aircraft was deliberately crashed into buildings, such as the C172 which was crashed into a Tampa FL high rise in 2002 or the Piper Dakota crash in Austin, TX.  There was also a case of an accidental crash of an SR-20 into a NY high rise apartment building in 2007, killing baseball player Cory Lidle.

Comment: Here's another intentional one:. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_Tampa_Cessna_172_crash

Comment: One more: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Austin_suicide_attack

Comment: Cory Lidle accidentally flew his SR-20 [into the side of a high rise in NYC in 2006](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_New_York_City_plane_crash).

Comment: All excellent examples.